# Having different logo and app name depending on the Language (Android developer / multilingual App)

Tags: android, eclipse, multilingual

Is there anyway to define a logo and the app name depending on the language of the user?

All of my texts are set on strings for this purpose, but my app's name must be different for each language, so must be the logo.

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Comment: Use a string resource also for your app name!? This is the basic setting given by Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

That is, use a string also for your app name referenced in the Manifest file, then create different folders:

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-fr/strings.xml
res/values-ja/strings.xml
```

Same applies to drawables:

```
res/drawable/strings.xml
res/drawable-fr/strings.xml
res/drawable-ja/strings.xml
```

And in general every resource located in `res`.

Here you can find more informations about available localization codes.